# flask-admin how to access model in viewmodel

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I want to access the model in a descendant ModelView like so:

```
class MyAppLibraryView(MyModelView):
    if model != Salary:
        column_searchable_list = ['name', ]
    form_excluded_columns = ['date_created', 'date_modified', ]
    column_display_pk = True
```

This class is used as follows:

```
admin.add_view(MyAppLibraryView(Section, db.session))
admin.add_view(MyAppLibraryView(Office, db.session))
admin.add_view(MyAppLibraryView(Salary_reference, db.session))
admin.add_view(MyAppLibraryView(Salary, db.session))
```

In MyAppLibraryView, model is unknown to the class. How do I access the models passed to the class MyAppLibraryView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [flask-admin code](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/3643d78808596f4634c8779e5decde9ef8ebda6e/flask_admin/model/base.py#L803), you can access model with `self.model`.

You have some ways to override `column_searchable_list` based on the model.

1. Subclass (the way I recommend)

```py
class MyAppLibraryView(MyModelView):
    form_excluded_columns = ['date_created', 'date_modified', ]
    column_display_pk = True


class MyAppLibrarySalaryView(MyAppLibraryView):
    column_searchable_list = ['name', ]


admin.add_view(MyAppLibrarySalaryView(Salary, db.session))
```

2. you can set it in `__init__`.

```py
class MyAppLibraryView(MyModelView):
    def __init__(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        if model != Salary:
            self.column_searchable_list = ['name',]
]
        super(MyAppLibraryView, self).__init__(model, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I am already leaning on the first option. It's reassuring that someone recommends it.